# Erro adicionado referência NFeRecepcaoEvento4

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, nfe

Estou com problemas para adicionar uma referência ao serviço NFeRecepcaoEvento4, SEFAZ Ambiente Nacional.

Endereço do serviço: 
https://www.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/NFeRecepcaoEvento4/NFeRecepcaoEvento4.asmx?wsdl.

Vou no meu projeto > "Service References" > "Add Service References" > "Advanced" >  "Add Web Reference"

Seleciono o certificado.
[image]

Na hora de adicionar a referência, acontece isso.
[image]

Comment: olá Ricardo, edite a pergunta e inclua a imagem na própria pergunta para ficar melhor e também algumas pessoas podem não ter acesso ao link.

Comment: Consegui adicionar a referência em outro computador, com o mesmo certificado e seguindo os mesmos passos descritos na pergunta. Ainda não sei a causa do problema.

Comment: Verificou se as duas máquinas estão com a mesma versão do .net framework?